# two .click instances [sc-player]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm experiencing duplicated events with `sc-player.js.` I want to perform an `iframe` change when my `li` is clicked however the `play/pause` buttons routes to perform the same `li` `click();`

Is there a way I can perform play/pause but not have it affect the `li` and vice versa?

**`li` action**

```
$("#page8").click(function(){
            $('#iframeContainer').fadeOut(1000,function(){
            $('#iframeContainer iframe').attr('src','slide1.html');
            $('#iframeContainer').fadeIn(1000);
        });
              });
```

**toggle play/pause**

```
  $(document).on('click','a.sc-play, a.sc-pause', function(event) {
    var $list = $(this).closest('.sc-player').find('ol.sc-trackslist');

    // simulate the click in the tracklist

    $list.find('li.active').click();
    return false;
  });
```

im a novice i know :] your help is much appreciated!

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {
      // 40 
   $("#page8").click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('li.active')) {
      $('#iframeContainer').fadeOut(1000,function(){
           $('#iframeContainer iframe').attr('src','slide1.html');
            $('#iframeContainer').fadeIn(1000);
        });
  
  }
          });`

It seems logical that if it does not have li.active class to not perform the fade. Is there a reason this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

This worked!

> ```
>   $("#page8").click(function(){
>           if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
>           $('#iframeContainer').fadeOut(1000,function(){
>           $('#iframeContainer iframe').attr('src','slide1.html');
>         $('#iframeContainer').fadeIn(1000);
>     });
>           }
>           });
> ```

If it does not have the active class then run the function.